# jQuery append element into X dropdowns with same class name

Tags: jquery

I have 1 - 20 dropboxes per product and each product have dropboxes with same class name (product_id).

Then I have another array from controller with information which product can be canceled with amount of quantity.

Now I have to append option "cancel" in those dropdowns with product_id X and quntity Y (information X,Y are written in array from the controller).

ex. `product: 1, qty: 3;` - that means that I have to add in 3 dropdowns option "cancel" but customer can order up to 20 products with ID 1 and I have to add option cancel only to 3 (qty) products with id 1 (other have to be without that option).

Here is my html code

```
//Dropboxes
echo '<div class="col-sm-6">' . 
    $this->Form->input( 'task[]', [
        'label' => __('Container action'),
        'options' => $taskAction,
        'default' => '1',
        'id' => 'task',
        'class' => 'form-control select ' . $product_id_calss . ''
    ]) .
'</div>';
```

This dropdown is in foreach loop and number of iteration is based on product qunatity.

I am making this with append option, but when I use class name this code appends to each product with that id (but it should be added only X times - x is defined in takingOffProductList->qty )

```
<script>
  var data = <?php echo json_encode($takingOffProductList); ?>;
  $.each(data, function (index, value) {
    quantity = $('.' + value.quantity).length;
      for( i=1; i<= quantity; i++){
        $('.' + value.product_id).append('<option value="3"><?=__('Taking off')?></option>');
    }
  });
</script>
```

I hope so that I have clearly explained my problem :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have properly understood your question:
You want to append x times same option in dropdowns with same class name. If it is so, than you can use `slice(0, your_count)` to take specific amount => `x` of elements with same name.

Here is solution

```
<?php if (isset($takingOffProductList)) { ?>
  <script>
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($takingOffProductList); ?>;
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
      var count = value.quantity;
      $('.' + value.product_id).slice(0, count).append('<option value="3"><?=__('Taking off')?></option>');
    });
  </script>
<?php } ?>
```